# What can stay between "struct" and "{" except the structure name?

Tags: c++, struct

A clear example of how data structures can be used in C++ is given [here].[1](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/structures/) This is one of the examples given on the linked page:

```
struct product {
  int weight;
  float price;
} ;

product apple;
product banana, melon;
```

However, I have a code that does not follow this template and I cannot understand it. What I have is given bellow:

```
struct result : mppp::data::table <
    row<semantics::user,       int>,
    row<semantics::exitdatum, spmm::date>,
    row<userid,                int>
> {};
```

I do not understand why instead of struct name we have such a complex construction and how it should be understood. Moreover, I do not understand why the "body" of the struct is empty (there is nothing between "{" and "}").

Can anybody please explain me that?

**ADDED**

Thank you for the answers. Now it is more clear. The `:` in the above example means inheritance. But what all these structures mean: `aaa<bbb>`?

Comment: The body is empty because whatever is required would've already been inherited and perhaps the developer needed a datatype which is a combination of such inheritances.

Comment: This is the inheritance syntax, more specifically private inheritance.

Comment: There are three features at work here: `result` inherits from a templated type called `table` in the `mppp::data` namespace. So which of inheritance, templates and namespaces is troubling you?

Comment: @andre - the inheritance is public because the type being defined is a `struct`.

Comment: @PeteBecker Thanks for catching that. It is public.

Comment: Why don't you read some introductory C++ book that explains all this instead of reading code and asking about every bit?

Comment: I'd probably have written `typedef mppp::data::table< row<semantics::user, int>,  row<semantics::exitdatum, spmm::date>, row<userid, int> > product;` or equivalently  `using product = mppp::data::table< row<semantics::user, int>,  row<semantics::exitdatum, spmm::date>, row<userid, int> >;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That code uses *inheritance*. You can specify the base classes of a `struct` after their name, separating them with a `:` character and, possibly, using one of the `public`, `protected`, or `private` qualifiers for specifying the type of inheritance (`public` being the default if none is specified (*)):

```
struct A { }; // Fine

struct B : public A { }; // Also fine

struct C : B { }; // Fine again, `public` is assumed by default

struct D : A, B { }; // Also possible (multiple inheritance)

struct E { };

struct F : public E, private D { } // Qualifiers can differ

struct : A, F { } obj; // structs can be anonymous
```

In your case, the base class is an instance of a template:

```
template<typename T>
struct X { };

struct Y : X<A> { }; // Fine
```

---

(*) *It is also worth mentioning that while the same qualifiers apply to inheritance for `class` types, the default is assumed to be `private` in that case.*

Comment: May be worth pointing out what that the default is `public` for `struct`?

Comment: @juanchopanza: Correct. Let me add that.

Comment: Obviously we are dealing with `structs` here, but I fear people could get confused and think it applies to `class` too if you don't say it explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

It is inheriting a template, but not adding any fields of its own.

You must read a C++ tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

It is inheritance like the case in `class`.
Therefore, in your example, `struct result` inherits another class or struct `mppp::data::table < row<semantics::user, int>, row<semantics::exitdatum, spmm::date>, row<userid, int> >`.

Answer (score 0):

A `struct` is equivalent to a `class` (other than the default access level). You can inherit structs or classes just as well. `mppp::data::table <
    row<semantics::user,       int>,
    row<semantics::exitdatum, spmm::date>,
    row<userid,                int>` is just that - a specialized template class.