# What does an operator without sign and two sets of parameters mean?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

[Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes2/) I see some clear examples of operator overloading. The syntax is as following:

```
type operator sign (parameters) { /*...*/ }
```

In the code that I work on I found the following string:

```
bool operator () (int a)
```

The first problem that I have with this code is there is not operator sign (nothing like `operator+` or `operator*`). The second problem is that in front of the arguments `(int a)` I see `()` and I cannot find out what it is supposed to do. Could you please help me with that?

Comment: You just cannot ask about every single [syntax of C++ that differs from Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15092844/what-can-stay-between-struct-and-except-the-structure-name). Please read one or more item from  [the C++ book list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 7):

You're incorrect about there being no operator symbol. The operator is the `()` operator. Notice that there's two sets of parentheses. The first set is part of the function name, `operator ()`, and the second set is the arguments to that operator.

The `operator ()` overload is called whenever you use an object for which it is defined as though it were a function. Consider:

```
struct greater_than_five
{
  bool operator()(int x) const { return x > 5; }
};
```

This class has `operator ()` overloaded such that when you pass it an integer greater than 5, it returns `true`. You could use it like so:

```
greater_than_five f;
if (f(10)) {
  // 10 is greater than 5
}
```

Notice that although `f` is not a function and is an object of type `greater_than_five`, we can *call it* like a function, with `f(10)`. This is a silly example, but demonstrates the use of such classes. These classes are commonly known as *functors* or *function objects*.

Comment: the first idea that I had is that `()` is the operator that we overload but on the web page that I linked `()` is not in the list of the "Overloadable operators".

Comment: @Roman Yes it is - it's after `[]` and before `,`. Nonetheless, that site is not a reputable source of C++ information.

Answer (score 4):

It means the instances of the class having that operator can be called with syntax like that of a function. This class can be referred to as a *functor*:

```
struct Foo
{
  bool operator () (int a) { std::cout << "Foo " << a << "!\n"; }
};
```

then

```
Foo f;
f(42); // prints "Foo 42!"
```

The `operator()` part means the operator can be invoked using `()`, and what follows is the parameter list, analogous to that of a plain function.

Answer (score 1):

The operator "()" is the parenthesis operator. You can overload it to take any type and any number of parameters. Here's an example:

```
class Vector3
{
public:
Vector3(float x, float y, float z)
{
    _data[0] = x;
    _data[1] = y;
    _data[2] = z;
}

float& operator() (const int component)
{
    assert(component >= 0 && component < 3);
    return _data[component];
}

private:
    float _data[3];
};
```

Usage:

```
Vector3 vec(3.0, 1.0, 2.0);
vec(2) = 0.5;
cout<<"Third component : "<<vec(2);
```

Prints 0.5